# Bash Script: options - case: range of multiple numbers

Tags: linux, bash, case, command-line-arguments, optional-arguments

I'm working on a script in Linux Bash, with different kinds of options to use.
Basically, the program is going to ping to the given ip-address.

Now, I want to enable the user to write a range of ip-adresses in the terminal, which the program then will ping.

Fe: bash pingscript 25 - 125

> the script will then ping all the addresses between 192.168.1.25 and 192.168.1.125.

That's not to hard, I just need to write a little case with

```
[0-9]-[0-9] ) ping (rest of code)
```

Now the problem is: this piece of code will **only enable me to ping numbers of fe. 0 - 9 and not 10 - 25**.

For that I'd need to write:
[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] (fe: ping 25 - 50)

But then there's the possibility of having 1 number on one side and 2 on the other: `[0-9]-[0-9][0-9] (fe: ping 1 - 25)`

or: `[0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9] (fe: ping 1 - 125)`

and so on... That means there're a lot of possibilities. 
There's probably another way to write it, but how?

I don't want any letters to be in the arguments, but I can't start with that (loop-through system).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about that:

```
for i in 192.168.1.{25..125}; do ping -qnc1 $i; done
```

Or in a script with variables as arguments:

```
for i in $(seq -f "192.168.1.%g" $1 $2); do ping -qnc1 -W1 $i; done
```

Where the first argument is the number where to begin and the second argument where to end. Call the script like this:

```
./script 25 125
```

**The `ping` options:**

- `-q`: that ping doesn't print a summary
- `-n`: no dns lookups
- `-c1`: Only send 1 package
- `-W1`: timeout to 1 second (can be increased of cource)

Comment: Would you mind to explain the options/functions used in your second piece of code?

I don't really get the `-qnc1 -W1 $i` and the `$(seq -f (...).%g` .

Comment: Thanks, and what does the `$(seq -f ` mean? Or do you have a link to its explanation? Many thanks, already!

Comment: @Kryptonous `seq 25 125` for example prints just all numbers from 25 to 125. `-f` is the format that this output should have. In your case: 192.168.1.25 to 192.168.1.125 if $1 is 25 ans $2 is 125.

Answer (score 2):

You can use extended pattern matching in your script by enabling the `extglob` shell option:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

So you can use braces with a `+` quantifier like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

case $1 in
+([0-9])-+([0-9]) )
    # do stuff
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Can this also be used in bash? As I see that you use `#!/bin/sh` ?

Comment: @Kryptonous yes, it can be used in bash, here's the docs http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html
I've corrected my answer.

Comment: I tried it in bash, and it works indeed. Thanks for the link! This really helped. The good thing is I can implement both solutions to achieve the desired output.